# Unable to change parents with Drive API v3

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I am in the process of migrating from Google Drive API V2 to V3. Basically I am copying a file, renaming it and then I am trying to move it to another folder. Copy and rename work correctly but the parent change does nothing. Below you can find a code snippet.

```
    Drive service = getDriveService("USERID");
    BatchRequest batch = service.batch();

    // I CREATE A COPY OF A FILE AND THEN I RENAME IT
    String documentID = ... // THE ID OF THE DOCUMENT I JUST CREATED
    // THEN I CHANGE PARENTS

    File newDocumentUpdateRemoveParents = new File();
    service.files().update(documentID, newDocumentUpdateRemoveParents).setRemoveParents("ORIGINALFOLDERID").queue(batch, new JsonBatchCallback<File>() {
        public void onSuccess(File content, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {

        }
        public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError error, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {

        }
    });

    File newDocumentUpdateAddParents = new File();
    service.files().update(documentID, newDocumentUpdateAddParents).setAddParents("NEWFOLDERID").queue(batch, new JsonBatchCallback<File>() {
        public void onSuccess(File content, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {

        }
        public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError error, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {

        }
    });

    batch.execute();
```

EDIT: If I use execute directly without a batch it works... Sounds like a bug.

Comment: I'm not having any issues. Did you check you have access to move it to the parent folder? Also, add some try/catch block to see what error is throwing in your application. Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: From the looks of it the problem seems to be that you provide an empty/new `File` object to the `update` method. You should either provide the actual `File` or use the `patch()` method instead, which allows this kind of syntax.

Comment: The reason I am using an empty File is because there is currently a bug when using the same object that throws an Exception. It may have been fixed in latest release though.

Comment: Just tried using the same object, still no error and still no permission changed.

Comment: @Andres no error at all, it always go on the onSuccess, tried with debug.

Comment: @konqi patch() method has been removed in v3.

Comment: @raz3r they removed something. The `update` method now uses patch semantics, so they must've removed the `update` method and renamed `patch` to `update`. Does it work when you're not using batch?

Comment: Yep with execute instead of batch it seems to work... Sounds like a bug to me... Every other function with batch works.

Comment: Here you can file a bug onto their issue tracker - https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/

Comment: Done! https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4330&thanks=4330&ts=1455869275

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
service.files().update
(
   fileId='fileId',
   removeParents='source folder id',
   addParents='target folder id'
).execute();
```